# What does a colon and name mean after a variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was watching a video and saw this code:

```
import { Connection } from "typeorm";

let conn : Connection;

beforeAll(async () => {
    conn = await createTypeormConn();
});
afterAll(async () => {
    conn.close();
});
```

What does the `: Connection` part of `let conn : Connection;` mean?

If I hover over `Connection` in my IDE, I see:

```
(alias) class Connection
import Connection
```

Comment: That's TypeScript, not Javascript.

Comment: `let conn : Whatever` means let variable with name `conn` of type `Whatever`, where type is one of the known variable types (i.e: `String`, `Boolean`, ...) or a previously declared class or interface. Typescript is a superset of JavaScript, allowing strict type setting, and the strict type setting is exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: Change the tag from JavaScript to TypeScript or add the typeScript tag as well

Answer (score 3):

It's [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org), not JavaScript. Specifically, it's a TypeScript [type annotation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), useful for static type checking. They're stripped out by the TypeScript compiler, which produces JavaScript files you use with the target environment (e.g., browser).